# How to Execute Stored Procedure ORACLE with EF Core 5?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-5.0

To try execute this method launch this error:

> ```
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
>   Failed executing DbCommand (165ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
>   EXEC SYSTEM.CLIENTESLISTA
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[0]
>   2021-03-08 10:19:14.220792 ThreadID:4   (ERROR)   OracleExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync() :
> ```
>
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005):
> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

```
public class Query
{
    [UseDbContext(typeof(DataContext))]
    public IQueryable<Cliente> GetClientes([ScopedService] DataContext dataContext) 
    {

        //List<Cliente> list;
        string sql = "EXEC SYSTEM.CLIENTESLISTA";
   
        var cliente = dataContext.CLIENTE.FromSqlRaw(sql);

        return cliente;
        //return dataContext.CLIENTE;
    }
```

Libraries Using:

Hot Chocolate 11.0
Net Core 5 Framework

Answer (score 1):

You should write it as follows:

```
string sql = "begin SYSTEM.CLIENTESLISTA(); end;";
```

If the stored procedure has parameters:

```
string sql = "begin SYSTEM.CLIENTESLISTA(:param1, :param2); end;";
```

The most important thing here are the two semicolons `;` into string query.

Answer (score -1):

execute-stored-procedure-oracle-with-ef-core-5 does not exist, stored procedures work with micro-orm libraries (Dapper).

EF5 Queries work directly SQL calls